# Get android services after call from C shared library

Tags: java, android, service, java-native-interface

I need call Java function from C shared library. This works good.
But There is initialisation of some android service in that called function and it is my problem.

**It cause error:**

> System services not available to Activities before onCreate()

and when I remove first row and give it to `OnCreate()`,it will crash on next row with

**error:**

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Intent android.media.projection.MediaProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent()' on a null object reference.

I am new in android and JNI and I have to do this :(

```
 public void requestMediaProjection() 
 {        
     try 
    {

          mMediaProjectionManager = (MediaProjectionManager) getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
        //startActivityForResult(permissionIntent, REQUEST_CODE_CAPTURE_PERM);
         startActivityForResult(mMediaProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent(),
         REQUEST_CODE_REQUEST_MEDIA_PROJECTION_RESULT);                
     } catch (NoClassDefFoundError e) 
     {
        String err = e.toString();
     } catch (Throwable t) 
     {
         String err = t.toString();
     }        
 }
```

**This is my code in C for calling of Java method:**

```
 jobject objx = (*g_Env)->NewObject(g_Env, cls,mid);
  (*g_Env)->CallVoidMethod(g_Env, objx, mid);
```

Comment: Sounds to me like you're trying to call this method before the Activity has been created / after the Activity has been destroyed, which you obviously shouldn't do.

Comment: OK. If I call my JNI fce from the same Activity as I call Java method, it won't crash, but I can't call another Java method. No 'onActivityResult', no 'new ComandAsync', etc.